# Controlling position: 2 XIBs using 2 instances of NSWINdowController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I am developing code to control motor focusers for telescopes. One or two can be connected (different USB productIDs) at any one time.  My code identifies how how many and instances 1 or 2 `NSWindowController` objects .  Each `NSWindowController` produces a slightly different window via 2 separate XIBs using `initWithWindowNibName:`.

I have used IB and `setFrameTopLeftPoint:` to control the position of both windows.

During `windowDidLoad` both windows appear in the assigned positions but once the code moves on to completion the second window moves to be tiled on top of the first window.  Where ever I position the fist window on completion of the code the second appears tiled on top of it.

Can anyone help ensure that the second window appears in its correct position ?

Thank you

Code extract (`DCWindowController` is my `NSWindowController` class):

```
firstController=[[DCWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DCWindow"];  
[firstController showWindow:self];

secondController=[[DCWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DC2Window"];
[secondController showWindow:self];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn cascading off using [setShouldCascadeWindows:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/setShouldCascadeWindows%3a).